# Make X axis labels show each day in Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a Gantt chart, and I need to make the duration scale to one day. Currently there's a label for every other day only.

See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The axis chooses granularity and number of labels / grid lines based on available space, so that it does not look crammed.

You can influence it in a number of ways:

1) Set (reduce) [`minHorizontalGap`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minHorizontalGap) for your value axis.

This setting defines how much free space there should be between labels. The less the number the more labels the chart will display.

OR

2) Disable [`autoGridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#autoGridCount) and set [`gridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#gridCount) manually.

With both approaches you might need to play around with the numbers to find the one that works for your chart setup and available space.